# Switch statement always returning the last case in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, return, material-ui

I try to make a password strength checker in react js. I use a switch case for highlighting the messages. but in switch statements always execute the last statement(not the default statement). I am new for the react js and I using the material UI framework.

This is the main function.

```
const passwordStrengthChecker = (password) => {
        const regExArray = ['(?=.*?[A-Z])', '(?=.*?[a-z])', '(?=.*?[0-9])', '(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])', '.{8,}'];
        const strengthMsgs = [
            'Password must have at lease one upper case',
            'Password must have at lease one lower case',
            'Password must have at lease one number',
            'Password must have at lease one special character',
            'Password must have 8 characters',
        ];
        const uiInfoArray = regExArray.map((regExString, index) => {
            const check = new RegExp(regExString);
            return {
                error: !check.test(password),
                message: strengthMsgs[index],
                index: strengthMsgs.indexOf(strengthMsgs[index]),
            };
        });
        const isThereAnyErrors = uiInfoArray.findIndex((obj) => obj.error);
        if (isThereAnyErrors >= 0) {
            setHideValidationText(false);
            uiInfoArray.map((obj) => {
                switch (obj.message) {
                    case 'Password must have at lease one upper case':
                        setPasswordStrengthText({ ...passwordStrengthText, uppercase: !obj.error });
                        break;
                    case 'Password must have at lease one lower case':
                        setPasswordStrengthText({ ...passwordStrengthText, lowerCase: !obj.error });
                        break;
                    case 'Password must have at lease one number':
                        setPasswordStrengthText({ ...passwordStrengthText, number: !obj.error });
                        break;
                    case 'Password must have at lease one special character':
                        setPasswordStrengthText({ ...passwordStrengthText, specialCharacter: !obj.error });
                        break;
                    case 'Password must have 8 characters':
                        setPasswordStrengthText({ ...passwordStrengthText, characters: !obj.error });
                        break;
                    default:
                }
                return obj;
            });
        } else {
            setHideValidationText(true);
        }
    };
```

these are my state,

```
    const [values, setNewPassword] = useState({ password: '', showPassword: false });
    const [validationText, setValidationText] = useState(false);
    const [passwordStrengthText, setPasswordStrengthText] = useState({
        uppercase: false,
        lowerCase: false,
        number: false,
        specialCharacter: false,
        characters: false,
    });
    const [hideValidationText, setHideValidationText] = useState(false);
```

this is how I show the error messages.

```
<Input
                            id="password"
                            InputProps={{
                                classes: {
                                    underline: classes.textFieldUnderline,
                                    input: classes.textField,
                                },
                            }}
                            value={values.password}
                            onChange={passwordOnChnage('password')}
                            margin="normal"
                            placeholder="New Password"
                            type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                            fullWidth
                            endAdornment={
                                <InputAdornment position="end">
                                    <IconButton
                                        aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                                        onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                                        onMouseUp={handleMouseUpPassword}
                                    >
                                        {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                                    </IconButton>
                                </InputAdornment>
                            }
                        />
                        <Collapse in={validationText}>
                            <Typography
                                className={
                                    passwordStrengthText.uppercase ? classes.passwordVerify : classes.passwordUnVerify
                                }
                            >
                                Password must have at lease one upper case
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography
                                className={
                                    passwordStrengthText.lowerCase ? classes.passwordVerify : classes.passwordUnVerify
                                }
                            >
                                Password must have at lease one lower case
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography
                                className={
                                    passwordStrengthText.number ? classes.passwordVerify : classes.passwordUnVerify
                                }
                            >
                                Password must have at lease one number
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography
                                className={
                                    passwordStrengthText.specialCharacter
                                        ? classes.passwordVerify
                                        : classes.passwordUnVerify
                                }
                            >
                                Password must have at lease one special character
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography
                                className={
                                    passwordStrengthText.characters ? classes.passwordVerify : classes.passwordUnVerify
                                }
                            >
                                Password must have 8 characters
                            </Typography>
                        </Collapse>
```

onChange function

```
const passwordOnChnage = (prop) => (event) => {
        setNewPassword({ ...values, password: event.target.value });
        passwordStrengthChecker(event.target.value);
        setValidationText(true);
        if (event.target.value === '') {
            setValidationText(false);
            setHideValidationText(false);
        } else if (hideValidationText) {
            setValidationText(false);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Try `console.log()`ing `obj.message` at the `default:` just to see what it's actually getting

Comment: I don't see how you bind the state to the input. Maybe its a problem with the variable being empty. Try logging as @Faissaloo suggested

Comment: inside the input, in onChange option, I call to the passwordOnChnage function, all the state are bind in that function.